# Solving recurrence relation: $T(n)=2T(n-1)+1$, using recursion tree and substitution

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Given this recurrence relation: T(n)=2T(n-1)+1, I am trying to find the tightest bounds possible. I have already figured the recurrence tree to look like this: [image]

Which would mean n levels, and 2^n work per level, meaning it should be O(2^n), correct? Assuming that's right, how do I begin to prove it with the substitution method?

Comment: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2014sp/recitations/24/using-the-substitution-and-master-method.html

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** You may obtain an explicit formula for $T_n$, by observing that

> $$
> (T_n+1)=2(T_{n-1}+1),\quad n=1,2,3,\cdots.
> $$

Then deducing an asymptotic expansion is straightforward.